# How to escape a single quote in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know I can use \', but that's not the point here. Let's say I have the word "can't". It has "'" in it now. This goes in to a var in a function like so:

```
function active(id,clas,match,hometeam,awayteam){
```

So let’s say hometeam has the value of "can't". When I try to use this code:

```
$('#test').html(hometeam + " VS " + awayteam);
```

It's not working, because essentially it has:

```
$('#test').html(can't + " VS " + awayteam);
```

How do I solve this?

EDIT:

I think the problem is not in the jQuery. The line that calls this function is this line:

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="1.4" class="butta" onmousedown="active('btn','buttdowna','match1','hometeam','awayteam')" />
```

So how do I escape this?

EDIT: I haven't found the perfect solution, so I just changed the word in my database and added the "\" for now...

Comment: if `hometeam` is a variable, than you don't need to escape it. And variable names can't contain single quotes.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle example? It should work as can't is a value, not a variable name.

Comment: The first method should work fine. If it does not, it's *not* because of escaping. (Escaping is to let the parser know it's not the end of the string. If a variable contains quotes the parser has no difficulties, of course.)

Comment: you haven't understand me right, the value inside the "hometeam" variable is "can't"

Comment: I do think I understood it as such. `console.log(hometeam);` should log `can't` if it contains that string.

Comment: @user1444739: Yes, we understand. Once the value is in the variable, you don't need any extra escaping to use the variable.

Comment: I think the problem is not in the jquery.
the line that calles this function is this line:
<input type="button" id="btn" value="1.4" class="butta" onmousedown="active('btn','buttdowna','match1','hometeam','awayteam')" /> so how do i escape this?

Comment: You need to post the code that creates the button. What you posted is pseudo-code that is of no use at all.

Comment: already posted the code that creates the button : <input type="button" id="btn" value="1.4" class="butta" onmousedown="active('btn','buttdowna','match1','hometeam','awayteam')" />

Comment: No, you didn't. You posted the HTML, not the JavaScript where you create it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. If the contents have double quotes then wrap the string in single quotes and escape single quotes inside.

```
var hometeam = '"can\'t"';
$('#test').html(hometeam + 'VS' + awayteam)
```

Comment: Edited my question. please view it.

Answer (score 0):

The values returned by variables do not need to be escaped in javascript. If you are having a problem there is some other underlying issue.

EDIT: Per your question edit you will need to escape the value in the function call, if you were to use `can't` as one of your parameters you would need

`<input type="button" id="btn" value="1.4" class="butta" onmousedown="active('btn','buttdowna','can\'t','hometeam','awayteam')" />`

Comment: Edited my question. please view it.

Comment: right, but hometeam is inside a php varriable : $hometeam.
so i can't edit the varriable, it is taken from a database

Comment: Then you will need to escape the escape character. i.e. `cant\\'\t`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using string operations to build HTML. Use jQuery/DOM methods instead and you won't have issues with this.

Another way would be escaping the quotes but compared to the previous suggestion that's just really ugly.

---

Since you are creating the HTML in PHP, do something like this:

```
echo '<input type="button" id="btn" value="1.4" class="butta" onmousedown=\'active("btn","buttdowna","match1",'.htmlspecialchars(json_encode($foo)).', '.htmlspecialchars(json_encode($bar)).');\' />';
```

Comment: That's not what i wanted. i don't need a function that creates a button. i need to fix this in here : <input type="button" id="btn" value="1.4" class="butta" onmousedown="active('btn','buttdowna','match1','hometeam','awayteam')" />

Comment: Well you obviously seem to use the value of the variable in your `onmousedown` and that's where the `'` is causing the error.

Comment: because i use php, the hometeam is equals to $hometeam which can be for example the word "can't". then i have this : 'can't'

Comment: Ok. Good to know. That's important information you completely forgot mentioning in your question...

Comment: Sorry for that... do you know how can i fix it? because i cant edit this php varriable, it is been taken from a database
EDIT: just saw you edited, i will try it out.

Comment: That's not good for me, I am using hebrew characters so it treats them as special characters

Comment: Doesn't matter. They should be displayed properly in the browser anyway.

Comment: It's not.
It changed one of the letters to \u05e6'... and it has " ' " in it.
is there any other way?

Comment: Both is **perfectly fine**. When displaying it it will be the correct character as long as you use UTF8 and the `'` is fine, too - remember, I changed the markup to use double quotes for the attribute.

Comment: Using your code gives me this in the source code : <input type="button" id="btn" value="1.4" class="butta" onmousedown='active("btn","buttdowna","match1",&quot;\u05e6'\u05dc\u05e1\u05d9&quot;, &quot;\u05d0\u05e8\u05e1\u05e0\u05dc&quot;);' />

and it does not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the HTML Part like this it will work,

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="1.4" class="butta" onmousedown=active("btn","buttdowna","match1","can't","awayteam") />
```

In an HTML attribute without Quotation also work. Quotation is used to group. Example) title="Click Event" will work and title=Click Event will take the first value(Click) only. That is if a word doesn't contains space then no need of Quotation.